# Microsoft_Office Customize installation on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS with PlayonLinux failed

Tags: wine, playonlinux, microsoft-office

Hello, guys how are you? I am trying to install office in my ubuntu. I managed with success to install all the necessary components and I configure the right versions of wine to work together with play on Linux.My problem now is when Microsoft office started the installation and i clicked in -> customized the installation it  doesn't let me to disallow what i want just like (OneNote,Outlook, OneDrive etc) and allow only the necessary like  (Access, Excel, Powerpoint, Publisher, Word) so my whole process was failed. What is the problem?? I search all the google but I didn't find something similar to my occasion. I would appreciate any solution thnx in advance.

Comment: I know it's not a  solution, but are you aware of alternative software? The OpenOffice/LibreOffice suite pretty much has every feature that the Microsoft variants have.

Comment: I have the same problem. I see many installations process and all omit this step. The only way is installing the full office.

Comment: @hiigaran I'm not a M$ fan, but OpenOffice/LibreOffice are too far from it.

Answer (score 0):

Many versions of Office are now packaged in the Click-to-Run installer, which doesn't allow customization

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-to-customize-installation-of-office/1c01bbf5-b5ad-4e3c-91ad-819f56c170c4